# How to append an ajax reponse image as a backround to some Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The following recieves a profile picture from facebook and appends it to #A.
But i want to append this as a background of #A not just an img inside #A.

```
FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {
var str="<br/><b>Pic</b> : <img src='"+response.data.url+"'/>";
$("#A").append(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it to the css of #A.

```
FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {
$("#A").css('background-image',response.data.url);
...
```